# Разбор Binding DataGrid и ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, combobox

Очень нужно разобраться с тем как работает ComboBox в таблице DataGrid на WPF.
Мне важно чтобы было грамотно разъяснено и правильно реализовано.
Изложу суть - Вывести коллекцию в DataGrid :
1. Есть коллекция телефонов (например) ObservableCollection collectionPones; (сразу вопрос - почему нужно использовать эту коллекцию, а не простой List или ArrayList ... ? и как "красиво"[Linq] приводить к такой коллекции уже существующие коллекции?)
2. В этой коллекции есть Param, который нужно выводить в ComboBox, так чтоб изменялась коллекция при изменении параметра в ComboBox, (типа Mode=TwoWay)

```
<Window x:Class="DataGrid_ComboBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGrid_ComboBox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=collectionPones}">
        <!--Не подключает - почему?-->
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="id Phone" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name Phone" Binding="{Binding Name}" 
/>
            <!-- Нужно добавить ComboBox listParams и увязать его с 
collectionPones-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Param">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox/>
                        <!--Как разобраться с биндингами-->
                        <!--ItemsSource="{Binding Path=???,  
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=
{x:Type Window}}}"
                            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding ???, Mode=TwoWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace DataGrid_ComboBox
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Phone> collectionPones; 
        public ObservableCollection<Param> listParams;

    public class Phone
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name  { get; set; }
        public Param PhoneParam { get; set; }
    }

    public class Param
    {
        public int IdParam { get; set; }
        public string NameParam { get; set; }
        public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitCollection();
    }

    private void InitCollection()
    {
        listParams = new ObservableCollection<Param>()
        {
            new Param() { IdParam = 1, MyProperty=true, NameParam="Sensor" },
            new Param() { IdParam = 2, MyProperty=false, NameParam="Capacitive battery" }
        };

        collectionPones = new ObservableCollection<Phone>()
        {
            new Phone() { Id=1, Name="IPhone6", PhoneParam = listParams[0] },
            new Phone() { Id=2, Name="IPhone7", PhoneParam = listParams[1] }
        };

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу первого вопроса.

`ObservableCollection` хороша тем, что реализует интерфейс [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx). Этот интерфейс содержит событие, которое уведомляет внешний код о изменении состава коллекции: добавлении или удалении элемента. Разметка WPF подписывается на это событие, что позволяет ей обновлять внешний вид элементов, если коллекция была изменена из кода (например, был добавлен новый элемент).

Другие коллекции приводятся к `ObservableCollection` посредством вызова ее конструктора, т.е. var `c = new ObservableCollection<T>(otherCollection)`.

Если рассматривать вашу ситуацию, то коллекция `listParams` вполне может быть типа `List<T>`, т.к. она задается один раз и не меняется (и, по идее, не должна меняться) в процессе работы программы.

По поводу второго вопроса.

Есть два важных момента, которых не доставало в вашем решении:

1. Привязка работает только к свойствам. Ваши поля должны стать свойствами.
2. Привязка работает к объекту, который указан в DataContext. У вашего окна DataContext не задан.

Более подробные разъяснения будут даны в комментариях в приведенном коде.

```
<Grid>
    <!-- байндинг отработает, т.к. DataContext задан  -->
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Phones}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="id Phone" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="auto" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name Phone" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Param" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Здесь привязка работает к элементу коллекции. У элемента коллекции есть свойство PhoneParam. К нему мы и привязываем выбранный элемент -->
                        <!-- Однако у элемента коллекции отсутствует перечень всех доступных параметров, зато он есть у контекста данных родительского элемента (окна). -->
                        <!-- Поэтому мы привязываемся к свойству родительского элемента с типом Window   -->
                        <!-- DisplayMemberPath показывает значение свойства вместо строкового представления самого объекта -->
                        <!-- Он нужен для того, чтобы выводить понятное пользователю наименование -->
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Params, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding PhoneParam}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="NameParam"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Param> Params { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitCollection();

        // задаем DataContext
        DataContext = this;
    }

    ...
}
```

Еще я бы посоветовал почитать про подход MVVM (а заодно и использовать его) и ознакомиться с интерфейсом [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Как добавить обновление при выборе в ComboBox другого параметра? Пока не кликнула на строчку в таблице, свойство коллекции не изменилось, а после клика меняется только та строка на которой был клик((.   Mode=TwoWay не работает(

Comment: Прошу прощение проблема решена: Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged